# SagePay V4.0 CHALLENGE has stopped working for me

Tags: opayo

I am working on a c# service that uses the V4.0 protocol of sagepay.  I am trying to simulate a 3DAUTH request by passing in CHALLENGE as the Cardholder name.
It was working fine earlier this week but today the response status returned is OK and the 3DSecureStatus is ERROR.
Looking at the test MySagePay Fraud Results screen, there is a red shield with the message "The Authentication callback message was Malformed..."
I have set the ThreeDSNotificationURL to a page that doesn't exist but could the error be Sage is somehow trying to validate this page?
I was expecting a status response of "3DAUTH".
Any help greatly appreciated including any tips on getting more info from the mysagepay console error.
this is part of the message I am sending in

```
&ThreeDSNotificationURL= http://test.somepage.com/testpage.aspx
&UseDefaultValues=True
&BrowserAcceptHeader=Unknown
&BrowserLanguage=en-GB
&ChallengeWindowSize=03
&BrowserJavascriptEnabled=1
&BrowserJavaEnabled=1
&BrowserColorDepth=16
&BrowserScreenHeight=800
&BrowserScreenWidth=1500
&BrowserTZ=-60
&VPSProtocol=4.00
&TxType=PAYMENT
&Vendor=mycompany
&Currency=GBP
&ClientIPAddress=127.0.0.1
&BrowserUserAgent=Unknown
&Apply3DSecure=0
```

thanks

Comment: Url in your question is not accessible, do check and make possible edits in your question

Comment: sorry,  not intended to be a url but an example of some of the data i am passing to sagepay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it (the test sandbox) is working again now.

Answer (score 0):

You need the ThreeDSNotificationURL. This is the page the bank posts back to after the challenge.

There you have to get the post values for cres, VPSTxID and threeDSessionData from the form and post them to SagePay. Then handle the SagePay response to find out if the payment was successful or failed or if an error occured.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue. Our code was working fine. We would pass "CHALLENGE" as the CardHolder and we would get the expected status but, at some point, we started receiving "3DSecureStatus=ERROR".

Has anything changed with the sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working again now.  Getting this response

```
VPSProtocol=4.00
Status=3DAUTH
StatusDetail=2021 : Please redirect your customer to the ACSURL, passing CReq.
VPSTxId={2FD68707-9DDC-76B8-2002-FBAE65F}
3DSecureStatus=OK
ACSURL=https://test.sagepay.com/3ds-simulator/html_challenge
CReq=ewogICJtZXNzYWdlVHlwZSIgOiAiQ1JlcSIsCiAgIm1lc3NhZ2VW
```

Must have been a blip on the test site.  Be good to know if Sage post release notes for these instances so deployment history can be tracked.

For info,  you don't need a valid ThreeDSNotificationURL when posting using Cardholder=Challenge.

Thanks all